# Convert JSON list into XML and keep the format

Tags: json, xml, xmldocument

I have a JSON file to convert into XML format with below fields. For "Formats" and "MediaFormats", they are list of integers.

```
    "Stars": 4.5000000000,
    "Reviews": 11,
    "Formats": [5,6],
    "MediaFormats": [1, 2]
```

My expected result is

```
<Price>29</Price>
<Stars>4.5</Stars>
<Reviews>11</Reviews>
<Formats>5,6</Formats>
<MediaFormats>1,2</MediaFormats>
```

I tried `XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode` but the actual result is

```
<Price>29</Price>
<Stars>4.5</Stars>
<Reviews>11</Reviews>
<Formats>5</Formats>
<Formats>6</Formats>
<MediaFormats>1</MediaFormats>
<MediaFormats>2</MediaFormats>
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post-process the result with XSLT. No off-the-shelf JSON-to-XML converter (or XML-to-JSON converter) is going to give you the result you want every time; you must be prepared to customise it, and XSLT is the best tool for this.

You can achieve the required format using

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name(.)">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=","/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Of course, if you're using XSLT anyway, then you could consider using XSLT 3.0's `xml-to-json()` and `json-to-xml()` functions so it's all done with one tool.